# Make longer access tokens with django_oauth_toolkit

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, access-token

I have set up the `OAuth 2.0` authentication in a Django Rest Framework project with the [`django_oauth_toolkit`](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit) library. But I have noticed the `access_token` length is quite short. How can I make these tokens larger? I mean, increase the number of characters each *token* has.

I have been searching for a setting to do this, but I haven't found anything. I have read all the available settings in the `OAUTH2_PROVIDER` settings documentation but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by copying the method to create tokens from [Github](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib/blob/7d7fe904af504c20f7d802650e54a78e3d0be8ba/oauthlib/common.py#L188)
changing the parameter `length` in a separate file and in `settings.py`:

```
OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {

    # this is the list of available scopes
    'SCOPES': {'read': 'Read scope',
               'write': 'Write scope',
               'groups': 'Access to your groups',
               'custom': 'Scope de prueba',
               'introspection': 'Permiso para ver información de usuario de un token'},
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 604800,
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_GENERATOR': 'api.custom_oauth2_token_generator.custom_generate_token'

}
```